# mirror a directory tree by hard links for file contents and symlinks for directory structure

Tags: backup, symlink, utilities, hard-link, git-annex

what is the best way to mirror an entire directory, say `original/`, to a new directory, say `mirror/`, which has the structure `mirror/data/` and `mirror/tree/`, such that

- every file in the directory `original/` or in any of its subdirectories is hardlinked to a *file* in `mirror/data`

  - whose filename is a unique identifier of its content, say a hash of its content, and
  - which is symlinked to from a point in `mirror/tree` whose relative path corresponds to the relative path of the original file in `original`,

such that it can be easily restored?

is this feature perhaps implemented by some tool in existence? – one that allows to flexibly choose the command for creating a unique identifier for a file by its content.

---

for instance, say there is only one file `original/something`, which is a textfile containing the word “data”. then i want to run a script or command on `original`, such that the result is:

```
$  tree original mirror
original
└── something
mirror
├── data
│   └── 6667b2d1aab6a00caa5aee5af8…
└── tree
    └── original
        └── something -> ../../data/6667b2d1aab6a00caa5aee5af8…

5 directories, 3 files
```

here, the file `667b…` is a hard link to `original/something` and its filename is sha256sum hash of that file. note that i have abbreviated the filename for legibility.

i want to be able to perfectly restore the original by its mirror.

i know i can write a script to do that, but before i do that and maybe make a mistake and lose some data, i want to know if there is any tool out there that already implements this safely (i didn’t find any so far) or if there are any pitfalls.

*background*: i want to keep an archive of a directory that tracks renames, but i don't need versioning. i know that `git-annex` can do that with a lot of overhead using git repositories, but i only need its way to mirror the contents of a directory using symlinks for the directory structure to files whose file names are hashes of their content. then i could use git-diff to track renames. i don't fully understand what git-annex is doing so i don't want to trust it with archiving my data. so i'm looking for a lighter alternative that is less intrusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so difficult to implement. On a GNU system (for `ln -r` and `sha1sum -z`) and with `zsh`:

```
mkdir -p mirror/{data,tree} &&
  find original -type f -exec sha1sum -z {} + |
    while IFS= read -rd '' rec; do
      sum=$rec[1,40] file=$rec[43,-1]
      ln -f -- $file mirror/data/$sum &&
        mkdir -p -- mirror/tree/${${file#*/}:h} &&
        ln -rs mirror/data/$sum mirror/tree/${file#*/}
    done
```

Note that it makes no attempt to preserve metadata (ownership, permission, mtime/atime, ACLs, extended attributes) of directories. And if several files have the same content, which  one will end up linked in `mirror/data` will be more or less random as it will depend on the order in which `find` reports them which is not deterministic.

Also note that empty directories and files that are neither directories nor regular (such as symlinks, fifos, devices...) won't be copied across.

Copying the directory structure across including special files and with as much metadata as possible can be done using GNU `tar`:

```
set -o pipefail
mkdir -p mirror/{data,tree} &&
  (
    cd original && find . ! -type f -print0 |
      tar -cf - --xattrs --null --verbatim-files-from --no-recursion -T -
  ) | (
    cd mirror/tree && tar -xpf - --xattrs
  ) &&
  find original -type f -exec sha1sum -z {} + |
    while IFS= read -rd '' rec; do
      sum=$rec[1,40] file=$rec[43,-1]
      ln -f -- $file mirror/data/$sum &&
        ln -rs mirror/data/$sum mirror/tree/${file#*/}
    done
```

Though beware that creating those symlinks in those directories will update their last modification time.

Comment: thanks, that seems to work. i've created a little script to mirror and unmirror a directory based on your answer, which i perhaps have to adapt a bit further. i'll wait a couple of days to see if anyone has another suggestion, like a tool for doing this or something similar; otherwise i will accept your answer.

Comment: oh, by the way. using bash, i've replaced `${{${file#*/}:h}`, where `:h` is a zshim, I think, by `${file%/*}`. is there a caveat to that when i know that `$file` comes from the output of `find -type f` or maybe piped through `sha1sum` or something similar, or do you think that’s fine?

Comment: `${file#*/}` and `${file%/*}` are kshism (from the 80s), `${file:h}` a cshism (from the 70), but having both and being able to combine them is zsh-specific indeed (from the 90s). `${file#*/}` first removes the `original/` part and the `:h` takes the dirname from that, `"$(dirname -- "${file#*/}")"` wouldn't work for dirnames ending in newlines, and doing `target=${file#*/}; target=${file%/}` wouldn't work for `file=original/file`. Also beware that if switching to bash, you'd also need to quote all the parameter expansions in list contexts.

Comment: ah, right. i leave in the leading `original/`. but since i know that all paths returned by find start with `original/`, so they contain at least one `/`, i think i can do `tardir="${file%/*}/"; tardir="${tardir#*/}";`. on files in `original/` this yields an empty string, but that's okay, since i only use that string to append to the non-empty path `mirror/tree/` for `mkdir -p` on a relative path.